# Questions/Comments since last visit

Tags: feature-request, questions

Either I don't know how to do it OR perhaps it should be a feature (feel free to change tags accordingly);

how do I

1. get a list of all questions since last visit?
2. get a list of all questions (for a given tag) since last visit?
3. see comments (to a viewed question) since last visit?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that keeps track of your last visit on the SO site is the Responses page.

You can also use http://sof.modos.org/tracker/update/#####, with your # being appended on the end, which will give you all activity on your rep and badges and votes since the last time you checked it.

Comment: and the responses page would be located ... where?

Comment: Click the envelope next to your name at the top.

Comment: That is only the changes to the user's questions / answers - it doesn't show all the questions since the last time the user was online!

Comment: Right, 'from last visit' information is limited.

Comment: @ a_m0d ... pllus it doesn't provide any context. It would be very useful to view a question and see (highlighted somehow) only those changes (new answers and comments) since the last visit. Right now, it seems like I have to rescan the question, answers and comments to figure out what is new and what is old.